# "Clear line" command for USART communication: which escape character?

Tags: c, ascii

I have an embedded device communicatiing with a host (with Tera Term) through USART. I realised the ASCII characters could be "extended" through the escape character `^[`. For example, `^[A` is "up arrow".

Is there an ASCII escape for "clear line"? Where can I find a list of escapes?

Comment: That's not ASCII anymore. And it's not ASCII escapes. You need to search for your terminal's escape codes

Comment: Depends on what terminal you asked Tera Term to emulate.  The DEC VT100 is a very common choice.  A company and product long gone but the original technical manual is still around: http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-tm/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This list](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) is a list of ansi escape codes. Your terminal may or may not support them.

Following the [more complete list](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) mentioned there, you can see the following information:

```
Esc[K   Clear line from cursor right   EL0
Esc[0K  Clear line from cursor right   EL0
Esc[1K  Clear line from cursor left    EL1
Esc[2K  Clear entire line              EL2
```